# I am not able to find the ASP.net Web Application template in Visual Studio Enterprise 2015

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I recently installed Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise Edition. I was not able to find the ASP.net Web Application template in it.

[image: Visual Studio Project Template]

I have already tried the following

1. Repair the setup.
2. Modify setup and uncheck and check Microsoft Web Developer Tools option.
3. Install Visual Studio 2015 Extension for ASP.NET Project Templates as outlined here. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2015/02/08/some-of-asp-net-project-templates-in-vs-2015-are-available-on-vs-gallery.aspx
4. Clean up registry keys, delete all setup files and clean installation.

What can I do to get the OneASP.net template to develop MVC and WebAPI applications.

Answer (score 0):

please refer the above steps to check if you can create a MVC project in Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise Edition.

If you still could not see the MVC project template in Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise Edition, I suggest you could try to delete ItemTemplatesCache, ProjectTemplatesCache folder and then run the the devenv /InstallVSTemplates switch and devenv /Setup switch. Please refer to the following MSDN document and then check this MVC project template issue.

Reference: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms241279.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ex6a2fad.aspx